# Django South added model to admin but gives DatabaseError

Tags: django, model, admin, addition, django-south

I've just started using south with an **existing** app, and after adding new models to the db, I can view the models in the admin, but when clicking on them to view the model details an error

I try to do the south equivalent of syncdb:

```
python manage.py schemamigration directory --initial

python manage.py migrate directory
```

where directory is the app name.

So when i try and view the model in admin I get the following:

```
Exception Type: DatabaseError

Exception Value: (1146, "Table 'omada.directory_drift' doesn't exist")
```

where Drift is the model I added to models.py, then registered in admin.py - omada is the site name.

**Further Information:**

Traceback from the django site ends with:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute


  114.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  201.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue
```

When executing

```
python manage.py migrate directory
```

I get an error that starts with:

```
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE `directory_building`
 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.
```

which doesn't sound very promising :S, and ends with:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler                
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1050, "Table 'directory_building' already exists")
```

Thanks in advance to everyone who takes the time to read this and offer help!

Answer (score 1):

You may find this [guide](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/ConvertingAnApp) useful.

Since you are only starting with South I would advice to start all over:

1. Drop your south table (south_migrationhistory) from your database
2. Delete the migrations from the app.migrations folder
3. Follow the guide

It is quite easy to get South in a bad state so you just need to get some experience with it. You however can't live without it as your projects grow in size.